# Active Directory ValidateCredential doesn't work outside domain in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm validating an user using Active Directory in my ASP.NET c# application. It is hosted on my server and works perfectly while I'm on my network. But can't do the same over the internet from the same application. I know, it shouldn't be the case for an web application. Please help.

Comment: What is the exact error, how do you test the credentials?

Comment: No error returned. PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(username,password) returns false.

Comment: The [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889.aspx) is crap. Use Wireshark to see whether the method performs Kerberos auth, NTLM or LDAP bind.